# How Do I Add A MouseMotionListener Without Implementing It Within The Class?

Tags: java, swing

I have a test coming up where you have to remember 9 small programs and write them. Problem is, I have a learning disorder and things often get very "foggy" for me where I can't remember things correctly - particularly big things.

The test is specifically "write these programs in the smallest way you can".

So I don't have to risk failure by fog - how can I implement a MouseMotionListener without implementing it?

The code my teacher provides:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class One extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener {
  public One() {
    this.setVisible(true); 
    this.setSize(400, 400); 
  }
  public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Mouse being moved...");  
  }
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX(), y = e.getY(); 
    System.out.println("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");  
  }  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     One a = new One(); 
     a.addMouseMotionListener(a);
  }
}
```

**Specifically, I want to not have to worry about writing methods that are automatically implemented - as I have several other problems like this - but with much more empty implemented methods.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smth. like this one?

```
public class One extends JFrame {

    public One() {
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400, 400);

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Mouse being moved...");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        One a = new One();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, this is exactly perfect. It'll definitely transfer over to several other problems! Out of curiosity, what does Smth mean?

Comment: Something :-) in short